# half pyramid inverted with even number

Tags: java

half the pyramid is inverted with an even number, and each line omits the starting and ending numbers, so that the output expectation are as shown below.

**Expected output**

```
2 4 6 8 10    
4 6 8    
6
```

---

but I have tried my code below with the results that do not match my expectations.

**My code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows = 5;
    for (int i = rows; i >=1 ; i--) {

        for (int j = 1; j <=2*i ; j++) {

            if (j % 2 == 0){
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

### **My output**

```
2 4 6 8 10    
2 4 6 8     
2 4 6     
2 4     
2
```

Question:

how to solve the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the starting value of `j` as well and limit how often your first loop runs depending on `rows`:

```java
int rows = 5;
for (int i = rows; i >= rows / 2; i--) {
    for (int j = 2 + 2 * (rows - i); j <= 2 * i; j += 2) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are starting the inner loop as `int j = 1`. Instead of a fixed start, it should be variable.

Replace

```
int j = 1;
```

with

```
int j = 2 * (rows - i + 1) - 1;
```

Comment: `int j = 2 * (rows - i + 1)`  is better, you avoid the useless first odd number

Answer (score 0):

The starting condition of `j` should depend on `i`, also you can remove the `if` using `j += 2` as increment statement

```
int rows = 5;
for (int i = rows; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (int j = 2 * (rows - i + 1); j <= 2 * i; j += 2) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 'rows' is a bad name. Can you see why?
2. here's the code:

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int columns = 5;
        for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < columns ; currentColumn++) {
            for (int j = currentColumn; j < columns-currentColumn ; j++) {
                System.out.print((2*j+2) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to understand the pattern. For each iteration, the number of elements in a column is decreasing by 2. So consider the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input = 5, multiplier = 2;

    for(int numberOfRows = input; numberOfRows >= 1; numberOfRows -= 2) {
        for(int columns = 1; columns <= numberOfRows; columns += 1) {
            System.out.print(columns * multiplier + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```